# Can't pass data from one page to another with React-Router-DOM (useHistory, useLocation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a router:

```
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <CustomPaddingContainer padding="0 0.5em 1.5em">
            <TableViewComponent columns={tableAccessors} />
          </CustomPaddingContainer>
        </Route>

        <Route path="/new-objective">
          <AddNewObjectiveComponent onSubmit={onSubmitObjective} onCancel={onCancel} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/new-kr">
          <AddNewKrComponent onSubmit={onSubmitKR} onCancel={onCancel} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/okr-details/:id">
          <OkrDetailsWithParams />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
```

and I want to pass specific data from specific component to one of this Route when specific button will be clicked. to be more precise, I have this component:

```
const AddOKRButtons: FC<AddOKRButtonsProps> = ({ parentObjectiveId }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const onAddOkrButtonClick = () => {
    history.push('/new-objective', { parentObjectiveId: parentObjectiveId });
  };

  const onAddKrButtonClick = () => {
    history.push('/new-kr', { parentObjectiveId: parentObjectiveId });
  };

  return (
    <OkrDetailsChildrenCardsButtonContainerCentered>
      <ButtonGroup>
        <LinkButton to="/new-objective" appearance="default" onClick={onAddOkrButtonClick}>
          Add a new sub-objective
        </LinkButton>
        <LinkButton to="/new-kr" appearance="default" onClick={onAddKrButtonClick}>
          Add a new key-result
        </LinkButton>
      </ButtonGroup>
    </OkrDetailsChildrenCardsButtonContainerCentered>
  );
};
```

I`m trying to pass the **parentObjectiveId** which is coming from props to the /new-objective page or /new-kr page in order what button was clicked. After that I`m trying to get that data in component where it should be with useLocation hook:

```
export const AddNewObjectiveComponent: FC<NonNullable<AddNewOKRProps>> = props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);

  return(<div></div>)
}
```

and unfortunately i got undefined in the state key, where the data is probably should be:
[image: empty useLocation state]

Comment: Where is this `AddOKRButtons` component rendered and is a `parentObjectiveId` prop passed to it? What sort of router component are you using? Can you expand your code snippet to include what & where the router is?

Answer (score 0):

Try to push history route like

```
history.push({
   pathname: '/new-objective', 
   state: { parentObjectiveId: parentObjectiveId }
});
```

I hope it will be work for you. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is also not working

Comment: Have you import useLocation & useHistory from react-router or react-router-dom ? Also which version you installed for both ?

Comment: Yes, I have react-router-dom (version 5.2.0) as dependency. I have no react-router as dependency because as I know react-router-dom includes all the functionality from react-router and it's just not necessary. All the hooks that I use is imported.